# Xarray load_dataset - float to integer

Tags: python-xarray

I have a dataset I'm trying to load into memory using `xr.load_dataset(mydataset.nc)` as part of a longer process. This dataset is a NetCDF and contains floats (I believe float64). I'd like to convert these to integers as I load the dataset to memory.

The reason for this is twofold:

1. The float values legitimately do not matter. Only the integer component actually matters. Loading the floats consumes 10gb+ in size in memory.
2. Cost containment - cloud computing with huge memory becomes expensive quickly. I have similar datasets using integers that take up several 10's of mb for the same number of dimensions and scale.

The NetCDF is a NetCDF4.

So: **Is it possible to use `xr.load_dataset` with some sort of flag to convert float to int (int16 is ok) during load?**

Comment: are you planning to convert to int32 or int16? note that the default integer type `int64` is the same size in memory as `float64`. how large can the values be?

Comment: @Michael an int 16 would be fine. The largest value would be 100, and the lowest 0, well within the bounds of int16. An int8 would work in this case, though I do have another file where int16 will be necessary later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this (that I know of) is to chunk the data and make the conversion block by block as you read it in. This can be done easily with dask, by providing the `chunks` argument to [`xr.open_dataset`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html#xarray.open_dataset).

Quick MRE which creates a 7.5 GB dataset of floats in [0, 100]

```py
In [1]: %load_ext memory_profiler
   ...: import xarray as xr, numpy as np, pandas as pd
   ...: xr.Dataset(
   ...:     {
   ...:         "myvar": (
   ...:             ("x", "y", "z"),
   ...:             np.random.random(size=(1000, 1000, 1000)) * 100
   ...:         ),
   ...:     },
   ...: ).to_netcdf("mydata.nc")

In [2]: ! du -sh mydata.nc
7.5G    mydata.nc
```

Loading the data directly as `float64` requires 100% of the data size in memory.

```py
In [3]: %memit ds = xr.load_dataset("mydata.nc")
peak memory: 6185.52 MiB, increment: 2796.45 MiB
```

Same as above, but converting to int16, requires a bit more than the first option, as the final array needs to be allocated and filled before the float64 array is dropped:

```py
In [4]: %memit ds = xr.load_dataset("mydata.nc").astype("int16")
peak memory: 8389.46 MiB, increment: 7594.40 MiB
```

Using `xr.open_dataset` and lazy-loading the entire array into the int16 array doesn't help, as the entire float64 array is loaded when it's accessed:

```py
In [5]: %memit ds = xr.open_dataset("mydata.nc").astype("int16")
peak memory: 8153.34 MiB, increment: 4532.12 MiB
```

Explicitly chunking the data and then converting to int16 in blocks as the data is read in does reduce the size, though the peak memory isn't fully 1/4:

```py
In [6]: %memit ds = xr.open_dataset("mydata.nc", chunks={"x": 10}).astype("int16").load()
peak memory: 3934.88 MiB, increment: 3695.10 MiB
```

Using dask, caching, and non-python I/O pushes the capabilities of the memory_profiler extension, so I wouldn't totally rely on these profiling results. Still, I think this points to the right answer, that the best way to convert types on load while keeping peak memory to a manageable level is with dask.